# Map collection size in Dozer

Tags: java, dozer

Is there a way to map collection size in dozer?

```
class Source {
    Collection<String> images;
}

class Destination {
  int numOfImages;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've updated my answer to use a custom converter at the field level instead of at the class level.

There might be other solutions but one way to do this would be to use a [Custom Converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html). I've added getters and setters to your classes and wrote the following converter:

```
package com.mycompany.samples.dozer;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.dozer.DozerConverter;

public class TestCustomFieldConverter extends 
        DozerConverter<Collection, Integer> {

    public TestCustomFieldConverter() {
        super(Collection.class, Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer convertTo(Collection source, Integer destination) {
        if (source != null) {
            return source.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection convertFrom(Integer source, Collection destination) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown value!");
    }
}
```

Then, declare it in a [custom XML mapping file](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
          http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
  <mapping>
    <class-a>com.mycompany.samples.dozer.Source</class-a>
    <class-b>com.mycompany.samples.dozer.Destination</class-b>
    <field custom-converter="com.mycompany.samples.dozer.TestCustomFieldConverter">
      <a>images</a>
      <b>numOfImages</b>
    </field>
  </mapping>        
</mappings>
```

With this setup, the following test passes successfully:

```
@Test
public void testCollectionToIntMapping() {
    List<String> mappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    mappingFiles.add("com/mycompany/samples/dozer/somedozermapping.xml");
    Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper(mappingFiles);

    Source sourceObject = new Source();
    sourceObject.setImages(Arrays.asList( "a", "b", "C" ));

    Destination destObject = mapper.map(sourceObject, Destination.class);

    assertEquals(3, destObject.getNumOfImages());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But by using custom converter at class level I wouldn't benefit from dozer automatic conversion of other fields (my real 'Source' and 'Destination' are richer). Nevertheless using your example I implemented the 'CollectionSizeConverter' which maybe specified at the field level:

<mapping type="one-way">
....
<field custom-converter="my.CollectionSizeConverter">
  <a>images</a>
  <b>numOfImages</b>
</field>

Comment: Indeed, it may be better to use a field converter in your case. But, well, I guess you get the idea :)