# dozer custom convertors for primitive types

Tags: java, dozer

the below url has an example on dozer custom convertors..

[Map collection size in Dozer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931212/map-collection-size-in-dozer)

but when i tried that example its giving the exception like this..

Type: null
  Source parent class: dozerPackage.Source
  Source field name: images
  Source field type: class java.util.ArrayList
  Source field value: [www, eee]
  Dest parent class: dozerPackage.Destination
  Dest field name: numOfImages
  Dest field type: int

**org.dozer.MappingException: Destination Type (int) is not accepted by this Custom Converter (dozerPackage.TestCustomFieldConverter)!**

is there any way that i can return the primitive types from dozer custom convertors..

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. This feature is not yet implemented. Please use old CustomConverter interface instead of DozerConverter to achieve the desired behavior.

Forum thread is here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dozer/forums/forum/452531/topic/3698691

Feature Request for tracking is here:
https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2997109&group_id=133517&atid=727371

Comment: This is fixed in trunk and will be published as part of 5.2.2 release this or next week.